# optimizing a slow mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, subquery

the following mysql query took 40 seconds to execute and it's too much

how can i optimize that?

```
SELECT 
    downloads.*, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT comment.id) AS commentsNum, 
    AVG(users_votes.rate) AS score, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT users_votes.id) AS rateNum, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT users_download.id) AS downloadsNum 
FROM downloads 
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT * FROM comment WHERE type='download' 
) comment ON downloads.id = comment.typeID 
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT * FROM users_votes WHERE section='download' AND rate>0 
) users_votes ON downloads.id = users_votes.voteID 
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT id,downloadID FROM users_download GROUP BY userID,downloadID
) users_download ON downloads.id = users_download.downloadID 
GROUP BY downloads.id
```

the result of **EXPLAIN**:

[image]

Comment: @FatihK what should i do?

Comment: does the `downloads.id` column is indexed? is it indexex when used as fk also (eg `users_download.downloadID`)?

Comment: @Paolo yes, it's primary key

Comment: @Paolo the `downloadID` and `typeID` and `voteID` are indexed

Comment: @MohammadMasoudian First of all remove `*` from your subselects and select only needed columns Second make sure the columns appear in `on()/where` should be indexed properly Third make sure you do have proper types for both pks and fks and the columns appear in `on()` part

Comment: Why all the derived tables? You don't get to use indexes on those joins.

Comment: @MarcusAdams can u explain more?

Comment: i answered my own question, please analyze query

Answer (score 1):

You should group result sets in join by download_id.

```
SELECT 
    downloads.*, 
    comment.commentsNum, 
    users_votes.AvgScore, 
    users_votes.rateNum, 
    users_download.downloadsNum 
FROM downloads 
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT TypeID,COUNT(*) AS commentsNum FROM comment WHERE type='download'  GROUP BY TypeID
) comment ON downloads.id = comment.typeID 

LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT voteID,AVG(rate) AS AvgScore,COUNT(*) AS rateNum FROM users_votes WHERE section='download' AND rate > 0  GROUP BY voteID
) users_votes ON downloads.id = users_votes.voteID 

LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT downloadID,COUNT(userID) AS downloadsNum FROM users_download GROUP BY downloadID
) users_download ON downloads.id = users_download.downloadID
```

Answer (score 1):

From your explain, it looks like the `users_download` table is the culprit. The query is forced to scan 100k rows from that table, I'm guessing it's because of the `GROUP BY` in combination with not hitting an index.

"Using filesort" is a warning sign, since it has to write parts of your table to disk to be able to sort (probably the grouping again). The disk is, as we all know, extremely slow.

I'm not sure what you are trying to do exactly, but `GROUP BY` is often expensive, so if you can rewrite your query without using `GROUP BY`, that might be good for performance. Otherwise, try to create an index that can help MySQL find the correct rows without scanning such a big part of the table.

Answer (score 0):

this is the optimized query

why this query executes very fast?

but the old query executes very slow?

expert programmers analyze that :)

```
SELECT 
    downloads.*, 
    comment.commentsNum AS commentsNum, 
    users_votes.AvgScore AS score, 
    users_votes.rateNum AS rateNum, 
    users_download.downloadsNum AS downloadsNum 
FROM downloads 
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT typeID,COUNT(id) AS commentsNum FROM comment WHERE type='download' GROUP BY typeID
) comment ON downloads.id = comment.typeID 

LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT voteID, AVG(rate) AS AvgScore,COUNT(id) AS rateNum FROM users_votes WHERE section='download' AND rate > 0 GROUP BY voteID
) users_votes ON downloads.id = users_votes.voteID 

LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT id,downloadID,COUNT(id) AS downloadsNum FROM users_download WHERE id IN (SELECT MIN(id) FROM users_download GROUP BY userID,downloadID) GROUP BY downloadID ORDER BY downloadID
) 
users_download ON downloads.id = users_download.downloadID
```